# Lebesgue measure of numbers whose decimal representation contains at least one digit equal $9$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, decimal-expansion

Let $A$ be the set of numbers on $[0, 1]$ whose decimal representation contains at least one digit equal $9$. What is its Lebesgue measure $\lambda(A)$?

Comment: When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: Hint: What is the measure of the set of numbers in $[0,1]$ with no 9s in their first $k$ digits? What happens as $k\to\infty$?

Comment: Oh, sorry ,this is my first time using this website. I will cover my idea and show where I am stuck next time~Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $0.a_1a_2a_3a_4\ldots$ be a number in $[0,1]$. If the $n^{th}$ digit is the first 9 in the expansion, there are $9^{n-1}$ possible assignments of digits ($0,1,\ldots,8$) to $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_{n-1}$. For each of these assignments, we have an interval of length $\frac{1}{10^n}$ of numbers having a nine in their expansions.

Summing up over $n$, we get our answer: $$\lambda(A)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{9^{n-1}}{10^n}=\frac{1}{9}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\Big(\frac{9}{10}\Big)^n-\frac{1}{9}=\frac{1}{9}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{9}{10}}-\frac{1}{9}=1$$

Comment: You're summing over $n$, not over $i$. ;)

Comment: Oh dear, thanks for noticing :) Will edit post-haste!

Answer (score 2):

We don't care about the countable set of $x\in[0,1]$ possessing two different decimal expansions. Denote by $A_k$ $(0\leq k\leq9)$ the set of numbers in $[0,1]$ having $k$ as first digit after the decimal point. The sets $A_k$ with $k<9$ can be written as  $$A_k={k\over10}+{1\over 10}A\qquad(0\leq k<9)\ .$$ The scaling property of Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ then implies that $\lambda(A_k)={1\over10}\lambda(A)$ for these $k$. In this way we obtain
$$\lambda(A)=9\cdot{1\over10}\lambda(A)+{1\over 10}\ ,$$
whereby the last term measures the set $A_9$.

It follows that $\lambda(A)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that a real number is said to be normal (in base $10$) if every sequence of $n$ consecutive digits appears in its decimal expansion with frequency $1/10^n$.

In 1909 Borel proved that almost every real number (wrt the Lebesgue measure) is normal. In particular, this means that $\lambda(A) = \lambda([0,1]) = 1$.